# Docker Containers can't communicate with each other (in the same network) on Mac Os

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-for-mac

I have two containers, "container1" and "container2" up and running in the same network. The second container exposes the port 8080 (in Docker Compose I inserted ports: 8080:8080). The first container tries to connect to the second container (using Java app, with the hostname as the name of the container and with the port using the port that the second container exposes), but it doesn't work. Using the shell inside the container1, i'm trying to do "ping container2" and it works, Docker resolves correctly DNS name and all packets are received. But using (inside Java code) as hostname "container2:8080", it doesn't work.

I've a problem only on Mac OS High Sierra and Docker 17.12.0-ce-mac5. On Ubuntu it works and I don't know why.

Comment: Can you post the compose file / commands you're using to start these containers please?

Comment: I agree with @johnharris85, it's hard to guess the problem. Also please check the known limitations in docker for mac networking https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds